# php-mhash installation

Tags: php, fedora16, mhash

How to install `php-mhash` in fedora14 ?

I tried below to install but it is not working properly .

```
 yum -y install php-mhash*
```

It says

```
No package php-mhash* available.
```

Please help me.

**Resolved :**

I followed the below process ,Now our applications is working fine .

```
wget -q -O - http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic | sh
yum -y install php-mhash
service httpd restart
service mysqld restart
```

Comment: The [mhash](http://blog.famillecollet.com/post/2009/06/30/PHP-5.3.0-Released) extension is no more provided. See alternatives [here](http://fr2.php.net/hash).

Answer (score 0):

yum will install rpm packages that are already included in repository

download rpm from http://pkgs.org/download/config%28php-mhash%29

and install it